# elasticsearch security with x-pack

Tags: elasticsearch

This is my `elasticsearch.yml`:

```
cluster.name: cluster
node.name: esn1
path.conf: "/etc/elasticsearch"
path.data: "/var/lib/elasticsearch"
path.logs: "/var/log/elasticsearch"
network.host: 0.0.0.0
http.port: 9201
bootstrap.memory_lock: false
discovery.zen.minimum_master_nodes: 1
xpack.monitoring.enabled: false
xpack.graph.enabled: false
xpack.watcher.enabled: false
```

I've also installed `x-pack`:

```
# sudo /usr/share/elasticsearch/bin/elasticsearch-plugin list
repository-s3
x-pack
```

Nevertheless:

```
curl -XPUT 'http://localhost:9200/_xpack/security/user/elastic/_password' -d '
> {
>   "password": "L5ngDgtl00?"
> }
> '
No handler found for uri [/_xpack/security/user/elastic/_password] and method [PUT][
```

Any ideas?

Answer (score 0):

You're almost there but i guess you're making some mistake in the command for curl. -u elastic option is missing.

See here: https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/x-pack/current/security-getting-started.html

Also, try to reinstall x-pack once by following step 1 in the above link.